# Get tt_content uid

Tags: php, typo3

I am developing an extension that allows admins to save stuff to the database.

And I want that each instance of the extension should have it's own Id in the database.
Is there some way to get the tt_content uid (which I guess is the extension instance Id) in the extension php.

Comment: You are mixing up the terminology here. An extension does not have an id. An extension is a specific package in TYPO3 which usually resides in typo3conf/ext or typo3/sysext. What you probably mean is "plugin" or "content element". I would recommend to clean up the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You fetch all tt_content's data in array:

```
$this->cObj->data
```

ie:

```
$uidOfCE = $this->cObj->data['uid'];
```

If you're using Extbase of course you need to get the content object first, ie:

```
$this->contentObj = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject();
debug($this->contentObj->data, "current tt_content's data");
```

Comment: Also how can we get content id in Typoscript like for eg. ``<div class="module" id="<need content ID here>">``

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way (Tested in TYPO3 9.5.4 & 10.4.3)

Get current content id inside controller

```
$this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->data['uid'];
```

AND

> This will return whole **HTML** of content which you can render directly

```
$conf = [
    'tables' => 'tt_content',
    'source' => $uid, //uid of tt_content
    'dontCheckPid' => 1
];
$html = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->cObj->cObjGetSingle('RECORDS', $conf);
```

Answer (score 0):

$contentId is content id in typo3 backend

```
$content_rec = $GLOBALS["TYPO3_DB"]->exec_SELECTgetrows('header,bodytext','tt_content','uid='.$contentId);
$this->markerArray['###content###'] = $content_rec[0]['bodytext'];
```

Answer (score 0):

For the effects of update that answer and know an plugin uid, you could debug `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\DebugUtility::debug($this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->data['uid'], 'parameter');`

If is not complete the debug does not show the `uid` because `configurationManager` and `contentObject` use lazy loading.

This works and tested from TYPO3 8.7

Answer (score 0):

Since TYPO3 v12.4, `configurationManager->getContentObject()` [is deprecated](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/12.4/Deprecation-100662-ConfigurationManager-getContentObject.html?highlight=getcontentobject).

The new correct way is this:

```
$uid = $request->getAttribute('currentContentObject')->data['uid'];
```