# TYPO3: Get content UID inside an action for a FE controller?

Tags: php, typo3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get tt_content uid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447983/get-tt-content-uid)

When a plugin (my extension) is inserted in a page, is there a way to know the content's UID inside an action from controller?

Something like.

```
class Tx_myextension_Controller_GalleryController extends Tx_Extbase_MVC_Controller_ActionController {
   public function showImageAction() {
      $this->initializeAction();
      $UID=some_method_to_get_the_tt_content_uid;
      $this->view->assign("var1", "Content UID: $UID");
   }
}
```

I don't have any clue where to continue searching as I ran out of ideas :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this trick to find all `tt_content's` properties:

```
$this->contentObj = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject();
debug($this->contentObj->data, "current tt_content's data");
```

That's an array so your solutions is:

```
$UID = $this->contentObj->data['uid'];
```

[This question was asked some time ago...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10448347/1066240)

Comment: I found it some hours after asking...and before that I was researching some time. Thanks anyway :) Oh, and thanks, this way is better, since the one I use is deprecated :)